# HttpClient Communication to WebAPI Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

Is there a good way to debug code from a console app to a web api project in VS2013?  For example if I had some code such as:

**Web API Controller**

```
// GET api/values
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
 return string [] { "value1, value2" };
}
```

**Console Application**

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var results = client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:35690/api/values").Result;
```

I know I can use a browser or a tool like CURL.  However, where this gets more complicated is handling a multipart form post for a file upload scenario I'd like to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the WebAPI service is part of the same solution as the console application, you can simply set breakpoints wherever you wish and they are respected.

Comment: It is part of the same solution.  However, if I start up the Web API project first - then stop debugging - then start up the console app it doesn't keep the Web API application going.

Comment: Ahhh - I just need to use "Start New Instance".  Great!  I am off an running.  Thanks!